# Regex: Use \b (word boundary) separator but ignore some characters

Tags: python, regex

Given this example:

```py
s = "Hi, domain: (foo.bar.com) bye"
```

I'd like to create a regex that matches both word and non-word strings, separately, i.e:

```py
re.findall(regex, s)
# Returns: ["Hi", ", ", "domain", ": (", "foo.bar.com", ") ", "bye"]
```

My approach was to use the word boundary separator `\b` to catch any string that is bound by two word-to-non-word switches. From the `re` module docs:

> `\b` is defined as the boundary between a `\w` and a `\W` character (or vice versa)

Therefore I tried as a first step:

```py
regex = r'(?:^|\b).*?(?=\b|$)'
re.findall(regex, s)
# Returns: ["Hi", ",", "domain", ": (", "foo", ".", "bar", ".", "com", ") ", "bye"]
```

The problem is that I don't want the dot (`.`) character to be a separator too, I'd like the regex to see `foo.bar.com` as a whole word and not as three words separated by dots.

I tried to find a way to use a negative lookahead on dot but did not manage to make it work.

Is there any way to achieve that?

I don't mind that the dot won't be a separator at all in the regex, it doesn't have to be specific to domain names.

---

I looked at [Regex word boundary alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14074308/regex-word-boundary-alternative), [Capture using word boundaries without stopping at "dot" and/or other characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48976902/regex-capture-using-word-boundaries-without-stopping-at-dot-and-or-other-char/48978221#comment84959578_48976902) and [Regex word boundary excluding the hyphen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196462/regex-word-boundary-excluding-the-hyphen) but it does not fit my case as I cannot use the space as a separator condition.

[Exclude some characters from word boundary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43400689/exclude-some-characters-from-word-boundary-in-javascript-regular-expressions) is the only one that got me close, but I didn't manage to reach it.

Answer (score 2):

You may use this regex in `findall`:

```
\w+(?:\.\w+)*|\W+
```

Which finds a word followed by 0 or more repeats of dot separated words or 1+ of non-word characters.

**Code:**

```bash
import re

s = "Hi, domain: (foo.bar.com) bye"
print (re.findall(r'\w+(?:\.\w+)*|\W+', s))
```

**Output:**

```bash
['Hi', ', ', 'domain', ': (', 'foo.bar.com', ') ', 'bye']
```

Answer (score 1):

For your example, you could just [split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) on `[^\w.]+`, using a capturing group around it to keep those values in the output:

```py
import re

s = "Hi, domain: (foo.bar.com) bye"
re.split(r'([^\w.]+)', s)
# ['Hi', ', ', 'domain', ': (', 'foo.bar.com', ') ', 'bye']
```

If your string might end or finish with non-word/space characters, you can filter out the resultant empty strings in the list with a comprehension:

```py
s = "!! Hello foo.bar.com, your domain ##"
re.split(r'([^\w.]+)', s)
# ['', '!! ', 'Hello', ' ', 'foo.bar.com', ', ', 'your', ' ', 'domain', ' ##', '']
[w for w in re.split(r'([^\w.]+)', s) if len(w)]
# ['!! ', 'Hello', ' ', 'foo.bar.com', ', ', 'your', ' ', 'domain', ' ##']
```

Answer (score 1):

Lookarounds let you easily say "dot, except if it's surrounded by alphabetics on both sides" if that's what you mean;

```
re.findall(r'(?:^|\b)(\w+(?:\.\w+)*|\W+)(?!\.\w)(?=\b|$)', s)
```

or simply "word boundary, unless it's a dot":

```
re.findall(r'(?:^|(?<!\.)\b(?!\.)).+?(?=(?<!\.)\b(?!\.)|$)', s)
```

Notice that the latter will join text across a word boundary if it's a dot; so, for example, `'bye. '` would be extracted as one string.

(Perhaps try to be more precise about your requirements?)

Demo: https://ideone.com/dvQhFO